# Change column value based in previous row

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, compare

I have a table like this:

```
| Group | Id | value |  
| :---- | :- | :---- |  
| A | a | 0 |  
| A | b | 1 |  
| A | c | 2 |  
| A | d | 0 |  
| A | e | 1 |  
| B | f | 0 |  
| B | g | 1 |  
| B | h | 2 |  
| B | i | 0 |  
| B | j | 1 |
```

And I want to add a column with a value based in comparison between previous and current rows under same group.
The column start with value 1 and will be incremented if the previous value is greater than current one AND this just can happen within same group.

```
| Group | Id | value | iteration |  
| :---- | :- | :---- | :-------- |  
| A | a | 0 | 1 |  
| A | b | 1 | 1 |   
| A | c | 2 | 1 |  
| A | d | 0 | 2 |  
| A | e | 1 | 2 |  
| B | f | 0 | 1 |  
| B | g | 1 | 1 |  
| B | h | 2 | 1 |  
| B | i | 0 | 2 |  
| B | j | 1 | 2 |
```

I tried this:

```
df[ , iteration := if (value < shift(value)) shift(iteration) + 1 else shift(iteration), by = Group]
```

But it's returning the error:

> Warning message in if (value < shift(value)) shift(iteration) + 1 else
>   shift(iteration): “the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used”
>
> Error in if (value < shift(value)) shift(iteration) + 1 else
>   shift(iteration): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (...)` only works for length-one conditions. One data.table translation user3640617's answer is `setDT(df)[, iter := rleid(cumsum(shift(value, fill = 0) > value)), by=Group]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Group=rep(c("A","B"), each=5), 
           ID=letters[1:10], value=c(0,1,2,0,1,0,1,2,0,1))

df %>% group_by(Group) %>% 
       mutate(Iteration = cumsum(ifelse(value >= lag(value, default=Inf), 0, 1)))
```

EDIT: previously I wrote "default = 1", but that only works if the values in every group starts with 0. I replaced it by Inf so that works even if the first value is not 0.
EDIT2: now it works properly when the values in two subsequent lines are the same.

Comment: Don't work as I would like  
If the dataset was

> df <- data.frame(Group=rep(c("A","B"), each=5), 
           ID=letters[1:10], value=c(0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,0,1))

It's still increment in when the current and previous are the same

Comment: Yes, you're right. I modified my answer (it should have been `value >=` instead of `value >` )

Answer (score 1):

```
 df%>%
    group_by(Group)%>%
    mutate(new = cumsum(c(1, diff(value)) < 0) + 1)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Group [2]
   Group ID    value   new
   <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A     a         0     1
 2 A     b         1     1
 3 A     c         2     1
 4 A     d         0     2
 5 A     e         1     2
 6 B     f         0     1
 7 B     g         1     1
 8 B     h         2     1
 9 B     i         0     2
10 B     j         1     2
```